# VC++ 2010: Weird Critical Section error

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, critical-section

My program is randomly crashing in a small scenario I can reproduce, but it happens in mlock.c (which is a VC++ runtime file) from ntdll.dll, and I can't see the stack trace. I do know that it happens in one of my thread functions, though.

This is the mlock.c code where the program crashes:

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

The error is "invalid handle specified". If I look at locknum, it's a number larger than _locktable's size, so this makes some sense.

This seems to be related to Critical Section usage. I do use CRITICAL_SECTIONS in my thread, via a CCriticalSection wrapper class and its associated RAII guard, CGuard. Definitions for both [here](http://ideone.com/LX7R3) to avoid even more clutter.

This is the thread function that's crashing:

```
unsigned int __stdcall CPlayBack::timerThread( void * pParams ) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    DRA::CommonCpp::SetThreadName( -1, "CPlayBack::timerThread" );
#endif
    CPlayBack * pThis = static_cast<CPlayBack*>( pParams );
    bool bContinue = true;
    while( bContinue ) {
        float m_fActualFrameRate = pThis->m_fFrameRate * pThis->m_fFrameRateMultiplier;
        if( m_fActualFrameRate != 0 && pThis->m_bIsPlaying ) {
            bContinue = ( ::WaitForSingleObject( pThis->m_hEndThreadEvent, static_cast<DWORD>( 1000.0f / m_fActualFrameRate ) ) == WAIT_TIMEOUT );
            CImage img;
            if( pThis->m_bIsPlaying && pThis->nextFrame( img ) )
                pThis->sendImage( img );
        }
        else
            bContinue = ( ::WaitForSingleObject( pThis->m_hEndThreadEvent, 10 ) == WAIT_TIMEOUT );
    }
    ::GetErrorLoggerInstance()->Log( LOG_TYPE_NOTE, "CPlayBack", "timerThread", "Exiting thread" );
    return 0;
}
```

Where does `CCriticalSection` come in? Every `CImage` object contains a `CCriticalSection` object which it uses through a `CGuard` RAII lock. Moreover, every `CImage` contains a `CSharedMemory` object which implements reference counting. To that end, it contains two `CCriticalSection`'s as well, one for the data and one for the reference counter. A good example of these interactions is best seen in the destructors:

```
CImage::~CImage() {
    CGuard guard(m_csData);
    if( m_pSharedMemory != NULL ) {
        m_pSharedMemory->decrementUse();
        if( !m_pSharedMemory->isBeingUsed() ){
            delete m_pSharedMemory;
            m_pSharedMemory = NULL;
        }
    }
    m_cProperties.ClearMin();
    m_cProperties.ClearMax();
    m_cProperties.ClearMode();
}

CSharedMemory::~CSharedMemory() {
    CGuard guardUse( m_cs );
    if( m_pData && m_bCanDelete ){
        delete []m_pData;
    }
    m_use = 0;
    m_pData = NULL;
}
```

Anyone bumped into this kind of error? Any suggestion?

**Edit**: I got to see some call stack: the call comes from ~CSharedMemory. So there must be some race condition there

**Edit**: More CSharedMemory code [here](http://ideone.com/6aCTe)

Comment: The two classes themselves look fine.  Can you show some code relating to HOW you are using them?  Are you sure the constructors are properly called prior to usage (no thread contention on the constructors?).  Are they being dynamically allocated (for some reason)?

Comment: Your class doesn't have anything to do with the CRT code, it uses Windows.  Debugging threading races and heap corruption is never fun, good luck with it.

Comment: @Chad: I edited my question. I posted the way CCriticalSections are used in the thread which crashes

Comment: I posted my response before I saw your edit.

Comment: One point comes to mind regarding your edit.  Critical Sections, and synchronization in general, is used to protect *data*, not *code*.  Your `m_csAccessUse` object seems like it might be superfluous to me.

Comment: `m_csAccessUse` is meant to protect the `m_use` member, which is the reference counter. I know, I could use the `Interlocked` API Functions. Would that be better?

Comment: Maybe better, maybe worse, maybe no different.  Using 2 critical sections where one would apparently suffice strikes me as asking for trouble, though.  Why do you need to seperate each piece of data with a seperate CS?

Comment: You think I should use the same Critical Section for the reference counter and the pixel data? That makes sense to me, though I worry it might increase blocking time

Comment: @JohnDibling let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2668/discussion-between-dario-ramos-and-john-dibling)

Comment: @Dario:  Unfortunately, I don't have time to engage in a chat discussion about this.  I have a few minutes here & there between compiles only.

Comment: I think we need to see more of the CSharedMemory class - probably the class definition and the constructor(s) implementation will do (we already have the dtor implemetation).

Comment: @Michael Burr: There, I posted a link to Ideone.com with the code, see the last edit

Comment: The CSharedMemory is different that the one you posted the dtor code for previously - does the newer version exhibit the same problem?  Who calls the `_unlock()` function in `mlock.c`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed it to use just one `CCriticalSection` instead of two. Problem's still there. `_unlock` is called by  `::DeleteCriticalSection`  in `~CCriticalSection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to adhere to the KISS principle and <del>rock and roll all nite</del> simplify things. I figured I'd replace the `CSharedMemoryClass` with a `std::tr1::shared_ptr<BYTE>` and a `CCriticalSection` which protects it from concurrent access. Both are members of `CImage` now, and concerns are better separated now, IMHO.

That solved the weird critical section, but now it seems I have a memory leak caused by `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, you might see me post about it soon... It never ends!

Answer (score 5):

The "invalid handle specified" return code paints a pretty clear picture that your critical section object has been deallocated; assuming of course that it was allocated properly to begin with.

Your RAII class seems like a likely culprit.  If you take a step back and think about it, your RAII class violates the [Sepration Of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle, because it has two jobs:

1. It provides allocate/destroy semantics for the CRITICAL_SECTION
2. It provides acquire/release semantics for the CRITICAL_SECTION

Most implementations of a CS wrapper I have seen violate the SoC principle in the same way, but it can be problematic.  Especially when you have to start passing around instances of the class in order to get to the acquire/release functionality.  Consider a simple, contrived example in psudocode:

```
void WorkerThreadProc(CCriticalSection cs)
{
  cs.Enter();
  // MAGIC HAPPENS
  cs.Leave();
}

int main()
{
  CCriticalSection my_cs;
  std::vector<NeatStuff> stuff_used_by_multiple_threads;

  // Create 3 threads, passing the entry point "WorkerThreadProc"
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    CreateThread(... &WorkerThreadProc, my_cs);

  // Join the 3 threads...
  wait(); 
}
```

The problem here is `CCriticalSection` is passed by value, so the destructor is called 4 times.  Each time the destructor is called, the CRITICAL_SECTION is deallocated.  The first time works fine, but now it's gone.

You could kludge around this problem by passing references or pointers to the critical section class, but then you muddy the semantic waters with ownership issues.  What if the thread that "owns" the crit sec dies before the other threads?  You could use a `shared_ptr`, but now nobody really "owns" the critical section, and you have given up a little control in on area in order to gain a little in another area.

The true "fix" for this problem is to seperate concerns.  Have one class for allocation & deallocation:

```
class CCriticalSection : public CRITICAL_SECTION
{
public:
  CCriticalSection(){ InitializeCriticalSection(this); }
  ~CCriticalSection() { DestroyCriticalSection(this); }
};
```

...and another to handle locking & unlocking...

```
class CSLock
{
public:
  CSLock(CRITICAL_SECTION& cs) : cs_(cs) { EnterCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  ~CSLock() { LeaveCriticalSection(&cs_); }
private: 
  CRITICAL_SECTION& cs_;
};
```

Now you can pass around raw pointers or references to a single CCriticalSection object, possibly const, and have the worker threads instantiate their own CSLocks on it.  The CSLock is owned by the thread that created it, which is as it should be, but ownership of the CCriticalSection is clearly retained by some controlling thread; also a good thing.

Comment: I don't see how this differs from what I did before, except it uses inheritance instead of composition and calls EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection in the equivalent to my CGuard class. What do I gain from doing it that way?

Comment: You changed your question to the point that now we don't know what CCriticalSection looks like, what CGuard is, or how either are related.  You say things like "Every CImage object contains a CCriticalSection object which it uses through a CGuard RAII lock" but unless we see how they are declared & implemented, we don't really know what that means.

Comment: Sorry, I removed that code because someone told me my classes were okay, and to avoid cluttering the question. I re posted it in Ideone.com, see the link in my updated question

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure Critical Section object is not in `#pragma` packing 1 (or any non-default packing).
- Ensure that no other thread (or same thread) is corrupting the CS object. Run some static analysis tool to check for any buffer overrun problem.
- If you have runtime analysis tool, do run it to find the issue.